# Separable but not Lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for a topological space that is separable but not Lindelöf. I am somewhat sure of it existence although I can be wrong.
Also, given a saparable space, can you give necessary and sufficient conditions for the space to be Lindelöf?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First consider the Tycholoff product space $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb R$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology. $X$ is separable, seeing as the product of continuum many separable spaces is always separable. Of course $X$ is also Lindelöf, being compact. However, if we remove one point $p$ from $X,$ the resulting subspace $S\setminus\{p\}$ will still be separable, but will no longer be Lindelöf.

It is clear that $S$ is separable if the deleted point $p$ does not belong to the countable dense subset of $X.$ In fact, since $X$ is homogeneous, it does not matter what point we remove. So let's take
$$S=\{x\in X:\exists t\in\mathbb R;\ x(t)\ne0\}.$$
So $S$ is a separable Tychonoff space. To see that $S$ is not Lindelöf, define;$$U_t=\{x\in S:x(t)\ne0\}.$$
Then each $U_t$ is open, and $S=\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb R}U_t,$ but no proper subfamily of $\{U_t:t\in\mathbb R\}$ covers $S.$